# Proving equivalent statements regarding two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets with universal set $U$. Prove that the following statements are
equivalent.

a) $A ∩ B = ∅$

b) $A-B = A$

c) $A ⊆ B'$

d) $A' ∪ B' = U$

I've managed to put something together for $a\Rightarrow b$ and $b\Rightarrow c$, but I'm struggling with $c\Rightarrow d$.

I have that for every $y∈U$,then if $y∈A$, then $y∈B'$, where $B'$ denotes the complement of $B$. It then follows that if $y∈A$, then $y∉B$, but this is where I am getting stuck? I'm not sure what this does for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in U$, *i.e.* $x$ is any arbitrary element. We need to show that $x\in A' \cup B'$.

There are two cases: $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$.

If $x\in A$, then since $A\subseteq B'$, $x\in B'$ and so $x\in A'\cup B'$.

If $x\notin A$, then $x\in A'$ and so $x\in A'\cup B'$.

In each case, we conclude $x\in A'\cup B'$. Therefore, $$U\subseteq A'\cup B'$$
We already know,
$$A'\cup B'\subseteq U$$

Combining the two we get,
$$A'\cup B'= U$$

as desired.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: wow, thank you so much!